# Is using a constructor function more expensive than an object literal

Tags: javascript

Is using a self defined constructor function more expensive than an object literal?

```
var obj = function(){
    this.foo = "bar; 
};
```

The reason why I ask is because, if I declare an object literal as such:

```
var obj = { foo: bar };
```

I wonder, if behind the scenes it does the same as:

```
var obj = new Object(); 
obj["foo"] = "bar";
```

If that's the case, I'd assume that they're both approximately as expensive, and choosing one over the other would be trivial (for a case like this).

Comment: Worrying about these performance differences is futile. `new Object` is never used.

Comment: @elclanrs Ok cool... it's sometimes the little things I wonder about the most.

Comment: None of your examples *declares* a constructor function, and `Object` is certainly not self-defined.

Comment: `new Object` is much more expensive, as it needs to resolve the `Object` identifier and call a function (you might have overwritten it!). The object literal in contrast is statically optimisable. And, of course, it's much easier to read. And a shorter string of code to transfer and compile.

Comment: There's always jsperf, and I believe this is a dupe, so there's probably something there already.

Comment: Woops indeed, missed that somehow.

Comment: Um, an `obj` function is very different from an `obj` object. Use what you need, not what is more expensive.